# Make a Random Integer from String list

Tags: java, string, random, integer

I'm trying to randomize some strings which have been converted to Integer.
But the thing is, my coding throws the folloing exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 2 3 4 5"
```

Here is my code:

```
  int sample = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());            
  int foo = Integer.parseInt(jTextArea1.getText());            
  String a = "";
  Random randomGenerator = new Random();
  {
      for (int i = 1; i <= sample; i++) {
      int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(foo);
      a = a + i + foo + "\n";
      jTextField2.setText("" + randomInt + a + "\n");                    
  }
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: what is the expected result ? You override the text in jTextField with every loop

Comment: From this post, it's not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: And what the errors are...

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. To help we're going to need a few more details. What errors did you get? What is your expected outcome, and what is happening?

Comment: Never ignore error by saying *some errors from java.swing, java.lang, etc...*
Look propery to your error and post it here

Comment: really sorry for the post, i'm new here
the errors are
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1
2
3
4
5

my expected outcome is the randomized integers from foo
at this line
jTextField2.setText("" + randomInt + a + "\n"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NumberFormatException` is caused when something is parsed to a method as a number but isn't recognizable by that method as a number. For example, in your code, this line will probably be throwing this exception.

```
Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
```

Where the text from the text field is something like `"1 2 3 4 5"`, the method can not turn that into a single `int` so it throws the error. You need to validate the input to make sure it is a suitable single number, such as "1" or "273" or some such.

You could use what is called a `try-catch` block, which will attempt to do it, but can define alternative behavior if it fails. For example;

```
try{
    int sample = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());            
    int foo = Integer.parseInt(jTextArea1.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException e){
    System.out.println("The text fields do not contain an appropriate number"); 
}
```

The above example **tries** to parse those two `Strings` as numbers, but if it fails it catches the `NumberFormatException` thrown and then runs the `catch` block.

It seems to me that you need to do a little reading on 'Exception Handling'. I hope this helps.

---

I have compiled an example of what it seems like you are trying to achieve below;

```
public String randomiseStringOfNumbers(String numbers) throws NumberFormatException{
    String[] sNumbers = numbers.split(" ");
    ArrayList<Integer> iNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(String s : sNumbers){
        iNumbers.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
    }
    Collections.shuffle(iNumbers);
    String sn = "";
    for(Integer i : iNumbers){
        sn = sn + i.toString() + " ";
    }
    return sn;
}
```

This method takes a set of numbers in a `String` that are separated by a space. If the `String` parsed to this method does not follow that format however, then the method will throw a `NumberFormatException` just like before.

Comment: yeah you're right, i'm trying to randomize the `"1 2 3 4 5"` what should i do??

Comment: @Engkid - I'll post up some code into my answer that does what you are trying to do, so you can see a working example.

Comment: i will dude thank you so much, and yes that's what i'm going to do lol
soon as my rep goes up :)